# how to create bell graph using google charts or any other charts and fill multiple colors inside the curve

Tags: javascript

Please help me.i am searching for above question.
since i have to draw bell curve with multiple colors inside the curve.
I have tried for normal density curve in Flot but with my data it is not proper

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Could you show us what have you tried? Have you tried something related to the result that you want? We help each other about "not working solution"; we don't create solution "from scratch"

Answer (score 0):

If you want "strange" graphics, I recomend you to create yourself the SVG file:

Google charts draw images using vectorial images in SVG format.

SVG format is a XML/DOM format that you may edit dynamically using Javascript DOM functions (like for HTML).

You have 2 options:

1. Use the Google charts and edit the resulting image.
2. Create yourself all the charts.

You may find an introductory tutorial for SVG format at: [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)